# How to append all the elements with the same id in a pandas dataframe row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below pandas dataframe, and I would like to transform into a sequence of elements into a single column without losing the temporal order of the `id` and `fruit` column.

```
id   fruit
---|------
101  apple
102  apple
101  watermelon
101  orange
102  orange
104  lemon
105  lemon
104  lemon
105  apple
103  grapes
```

For example, the new dataframe should look like this `(*)`:

```
id               col
101  apple, watermelon, orange
102  apple, orange
103  grapes
104  lemon, lemon
105  apple
```

I tried to:

```
f = {'url' : lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist()}
df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(f).reindex(columns=df.columns)


def foo(row):
    #just to remove the brackets
    return ', '.join(row)

df4['url'] = df4['fruit'].apply(tweak)
df4
```

However, although this is working when I do:

```
list(df.loc[[362]]['fruit'])
```

The collected information in each row is not temporally sorted (following the order of appearance order of the `fruit` column). Thus, how can I get (*)?

Comment: df.groupby('id').fruit.apply(','.join)

Comment: @Wen thanks!, although this seems to work for some reason I am losing the `id`  column(i.e. it seems to be reset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `groupby` + `unique`, followed by `agg`.

```
df.groupby('id').fruit.unique().agg(', '.join).reset_index()

    id                      fruit
0  101  apple, watermelon, orange
1  102              apple, orange
2  103                     grapes
3  104                      lemon
4  105               lemon, apple
```

Note that data within groups are not reordered, even if the groups are. If you don't want to sort the groups either, use `sort=False`.

```
df.groupby('id', sort=False).fruit.unique().agg(', '.join).reset_index()

    id                      fruit
0  101  apple, watermelon, orange
1  102              apple, orange
2  104                      lemon
3  105               lemon, apple
4  103                     grapes
```

Comment: @tumbleweed Add `.reset_index()` at the end.

Comment: @tumbleweed no you didn't. Why would columns disappear like that? It's right there as my answer shows.

Comment: Did you reset the index before you called agg? You should call reset_index afterwards.

Comment: I tried to print the shape of the dataframe and is: `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` and `(12436,)` respectively

Comment: @tumbleweed I'm sorry, but you're doing something that I am not aware of, or that I didn't advise you to do... are you running my first or second code?

Comment: There was a little mistake in the above code... the `unique` function. I want to preserve all the elements, no matter if they repeat. Thus, I am using: `df.groupby('id', sort=False).fruit.agg(', '.join)`

Comment: @tumbleweed Try `df.groupby('id', sort=False).fruit.agg(', '.join).reset_index()`?

Answer (score 4):

`apply` `join` with `set`

```
df.groupby('id').fruit.apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x))).reset_index()
Out[82]: 
    id                    fruit
0  101  apple,watermelon,orange
1  102             apple,orange
2  103                   grapes
3  104                    lemon
4  105              apple,lemon
```